# For loop unintentionally skips over item when trying to filter a list using items from another list

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, output, chess

I am working on finding all possible moves on a chessboard for a given position.  I am trying to filter out all positions a piece is on to make a 2d array of the board with just the open positions.  However, while filtering each row of the array it skips over every other item.

Code:

```
files = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

ranks_n = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
ranks = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']

board = [
    ['A8','B8','C8','D8','E8','F8','G8','H8'],
    ['A7','B7','C7','D7','E7','F7','G7','H7'],
    ['A6','B6','C6','D6','E6','F6','G6','H6'],
    ['A5','B5','C5','D5','E5','F5','G5','H5'],
    ['A4','B4','C4','D4','E4','F4','G4','H4'],
    ['A3','B3','C3','D3','E3','F3','G3','H3'],
    ['A2','B2','C2','D2','E2','F2','G2','H2'],
    ['A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1'],
]

board_n = [
    [18,28,38,48,58,68,78,88],
    [17,27,37,47,57,67,77,87],
    [16,26,36,46,56,66,76,86],
    [15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85],
    [14,24,34,44,54,64,74,84],
    [13,23,33,43,53,63,73,83],
    [12,22,32,42,52,62,72,82],
    [11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81]
]
white = {
    'p1': 'A2',
    'p2': 'B2',
    'p3': 'C2',
    'p4': 'D2',
    'p5': 'E2',
    'p6': 'F2',
    'p7': 'G2',
    'p8': 'H2',
    'R1': 'A1',
    'N1': 'B1',
    'B1': 'C1',
    'Q': 'D1',
    'K': 'E1',
    'B2': 'F1',
    'N2': 'G1',
    'R2': 'H1',
}

black = {
    'p1': 'A7',
    'p2': 'B7',
    'p3': 'C7',
    'p4': 'D7',
    'p5': 'E7',
    'p6': 'F7',
    'p7': 'G7',
    'p8': 'H7',
    'R1': 'A8',
    'N1': 'B8',
    'B1': 'C8',
    'Q': 'D8',
    'K': 'E8',
    'B2': 'F8',
    'N2': 'G8',
    'R2': 'H8',
}

b_keys=list(black.keys())
b_values=list(black.values())

w_keys=list(white.keys())
w_values=list(white.values())

pos_board = []
board_file = []
for b in board:
  board_file = b
  for n in b:
    if n in w_values or n in b_values:
      print(n)
      board_file.remove(n)
  pos_board.append(board_file)

for p in pos_board:
  print(p)
```

Output:

```
C8
E8
G8
A7
C7
E7
G7
A2
C2
E2
G2
A1
C1
E1
G1
['B8', 'D8', 'F8', 'H8']
['B7', 'D7', 'F7', 'H7']
['A6', 'B6', 'C6', 'D6', 'E6', 'F6', 'G6', 'H6']
['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5', 'E5', 'F5', 'G5', 'H5']
['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4', 'F4', 'G4', 'H4']
['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'E3', 'F3', 'G3', 'H3']
['B2', 'D2', 'F2', 'H2']
['B1', 'D1', 'F1', 'H1']
```

The 1st, 2nd, 7th, and 8th ranks should be completely empty because there are all pieces there but it shows that there are no pieces on files B, D, F, and H for those ranks.

Comment: Just realized a line of code got cut off at the very top ```files_n = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]```

Comment: A classic error. Don't remove an item while iterating over a list.

Comment: first of all the variable board_file contains rows, not files. ['A8','B8','C8','D8','E8','F8','G8','H8'] is a 8th row.

Comment: This will be extremely slow later on when you apply negamax or similar to the framework. Instead you can at the start of the game create a 8x8 board with where the pieces are located, then when you make a move you update this list to reflect the move. Then you don't have to loop over the entire board for every position. 

I would also suggest using numbers instead of letters, for both the board and the pieces. This is way faster and will also make your logic much easier later on.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this one. I replaced the board_file with board_row and put the initialization inside the loop.

```
b_keys=list(black.keys())
b_values=list(black.values())

w_keys=list(white.keys())
w_values=list(white.values())

pos_board = []
for b in board:
  board_row = []
  for n in b:
    if n not in w_values + b_values:
        board_row.append(n)
  pos_board.append(board_row)

for p in pos_board:
  print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

`board_file` is actually just an alias for `b`. So when you remove `n` from `board_file`, you are also removing it from `b`. To prevent this, you can make a deepcopy of `b`

```
from copy import deepcopy

pos_board = []
board_file = []
for b in board:
  board_file = deepcopy(b)
  for n in b:
    if n in w_values or n in b_values:
      print(n)
      board_file.remove(n)
  pos_board.append(board_file)

for p in pos_board:
  print(p)
```